# Manipulate issue

Tags: manipulate

I am new to Mathematica and so far I was able to find answers to my problems so far, but not for this one. I hope you are able to help me. 
I have 4 variables that determine a feasible "area". It the outcome of Reduce. I tried to visualize it using manipulate and PlotRegion3D, but I am confident that the visual outcome is not a right one, as many "areas" are missing in the visual. Here is the code I use:

```
Manipulate[
RegionPlot3D[(1/3 < x <= 5/8 && 
 1/2 (1 - x) < z < 1/7 (2 + x) && (1 - x - 2 z)/(-1 - 2 x + 5 z) <
   theta < 1 && 
 0 < y < (1 - 2 theta - x - theta x - 2 z - 2 theta z)/(
   2 (-2 + theta) theta) - 
   3/2 Sqrt[-((-1 + 2 x - 2 theta x - x^2 + 2 theta x^2 - 
      theta^2 x^2 + 4 z + 4 theta z - 4 theta^2 z - 4 x z - 
      4 z^2 - 8 theta z^2 + 
      4 theta^2 z^2)/((-2 + theta)^2 theta^2))]) || (5/8 < x < 1 &&
  1/2 (1 - x) < z < 1 - x && (1 - x - 2 z)/(-1 - 2 x + 5 z) < 
  theta < 1 && 
 0 < y < (1 - 2 theta - x - theta x - 2 z - 2 theta z)/(
   2 (-2 + theta) theta) - 
   3/2 Sqrt[-((-1 + 2 x - 2 theta x - x^2 + 2 theta x^2 - 
      theta^2 x^2 + 4 z + 4 theta z - 4 theta^2 z - 4 x z - 
      4 z^2 - 8 theta z^2 + 
      4 theta^2 z^2)/((-2 + theta)^2 theta^2))]) , {z, 0, 1}, {y,0, 1}, {theta, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {Subscript[q, 0], Subscript[c, s], \[Theta]}], {{x, 1/3, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(b\)]\)"}, 1/3, 1}]
```

Comment: You need more `PlotPoints -> 50` for `RegionPlot3D`.